# Universally apply restriction to bucket policy, for all S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to apply a specific restriction to all S3 buckets. Generally AWS published resources describe a per bucket solution. However this does not solve the issue of other users creating bucket policies that can circumvent a given restriction.

Take the following for instance: [s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only.html), herewith an example of the relevant restriction:

```
{
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      }
    }
```

It does not matter whether this can only be done for new buckets, however a retrospective application would be a bonus.
There does not seem to be a bucket policy hierarchy, so my question is basically, what is the recommended method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use an AWS Service Control Policy, attached to your AWS Organisation OUs. The snippet below only enforces S3 encryption in transit, but you can also enforce:

- S3 / EBS / RDS encryption at rest (probably other services too)
- Allowed EC2 sizes / families
- Creation of default VPCs
- Disabling default EBS encryption
- Deactivation of security services
- Root user doing much (they shouldn't do anything, really)
- Region enforcement
- Whitelist services for the OU

I might not have the brackets quite right, I cut this out of a larger SCP, but any IDE like VSCode can help with that.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "S3EncryptionInTransit",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
          "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
            "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": ["AES256", "aws:kms"]
          }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: It think this is a great answer, and I thank you for taking the time and being so detailed in your response.

Comment: However if others come here looking for a true in every way solution... this does not tick the "universally" box. Take for instance the following condition *s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only*. To effect this, one needs to deny all requests that do not have "aws:SecureTransport". See more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only.html
I'd like to accept your answer, but if I am going to do that, then I'm going to have to then change the title of my question... and clarify that this solution is only valid... most of the time, or sometimes.

Comment: You're right, this enforces encryption at rest. I wonder though if AWS S3 lets you upload with those heads over an http channel... I suspect not but I can't find a reference right now. A bucket policy with "aws:SecureTransport" is the proper solution but it's not AWS wide. You might be able to to enforce a bucket policy with that condition or something tricky like that. I'll ponder it.